# Difference between $(callback) and $(document).ready(function)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, document-ready

On the jQuery site, the description for `$(callback)` was that it behaves the same as `$(document).ready(function)` but then the examples showed some differences between the two syntaxes.  So I was wondering, does anyone know exactly what the differences between the two are?

Comment: What differences are you talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no differences, and the docs don't show any difference:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - $(document).ready(handler)
> - $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> - $(handler)

Straight from: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

I think you are confused by the example showing `jQuery(function($){ ... });`
Which is just a way of calling `$(handler)`, with no `$` conflict.

IE.

```
// Here `$` is used by another library
jQuery(function($){
    // Here `$` refers to jQuery
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

> Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all, except that the shortcut is very slightly slower as it has to decide the type of the argument and then call `$(document).ready`. (Actually the source code of jQuery is very clean so you can easily check for yourself - `$()` [calls](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L4) `$.fn.init`, which [goes through a couple of tests](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L81) then calls `ready` at line 177.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.
If you call `$()` with just one parameter - a function: `$(some_function)` - it means, that it will call `$(document).ready(some_function)`

So, for simplicity, you could use:

```
$(function(){
// your code
});
```

P.S. Don't use this structure if you are using different libraries (that can conflict with $ variable). In these cases use:

```
jQuery(function(){
// your code
});
```