# What's the difference between using (document).ready and jQuery(function ($)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)

I have always used:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Code goes here
});
```

And inserted my jQuery/JavaScript code therein (so that it waits on the html page to be fully loaded before running any code).

Lately, I have seen this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //Code goes here
});
```

I have searched for what the difference is here (mainly what the 'jQuery' part is all about).

My questions:

- What does the `jQuery` part of the latter code block do, if anything?
- What is the '($)' argument doing for that function?
- Is there even a difference (other than making the page wait to be loaded) between my two code block examples?

Comment: There is no difference. The `$` argument will serve as a local reference to the jQuery object; it's passed to such functions by the library. [Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Comment: Its the same, sometimes $ can get confused with other js libraries so that may be why people use jQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/) / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593292/ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068916/ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894777/ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524496/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is the closure around the `$` variable. The first snippet assumes that the `$` variable has not been released (by using [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) or if another library you are using also makes use of `$` but not as the jQuery variable).

The second implementation is safer because it doesn't make any assumptions but allows your internal code to safely use the `$` variable by making it a parameter.

Comment: So, as I have no reason not to, I should use the second snippet, just to be safe in the future (in case I am using jQuery in a different environment, using .noConflict, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. It's the proactive solution as opposed to waiting for something to potentially break.

Comment: And, just to be clear, the jQuery(function($) will always wait until the document is ready?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific, jQuery(function(){}); is short hand for jQuery(function($){ });

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will replace my document.ready(s) as I see them :) Another thing to clarify, jQuery(function(){}); = jQuery(function($){}); as the former is shorthand? Any reason to ever use the latter?

Answer (score 2):

It is the same thing:

Using `jQuery(function(){})` is just a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function (){});`

**Note:** you can use `$` or `jQuery`

Comment: Unless .noConflict was called.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same.  [**From the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

```
JQuery Call back (jQuery( callback ))
```

> "This function behaves just like $(document).ready(), in that it should be used to wrap other $() operations on your page that depend on the DOM being ready. While this function is, technically, chainable, there really isn't much use for chaining against it."

Answer (score 0):

They are nearly the same.

In the second function you are passing in `jQuery` i.e. `$` into the function. `$` is shorthand for the `jQuery`.

Straight from the jQuery library code for when you call `$()`

```
// tests to see if you passed in a function
} else if (jQuery.isFunction(selector)) { 
    // adds the function to be called when jQuery fires the ready event
    return rootjQuery.ready(selector); 
}
```

Comments are mine.